# Show only one group in scatter plot using 'ggpubr' in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, ggpubr

I would like to generate a scatter plot in R using 'ggpubr', but only show the data from one group. Using the mtcars data as an example, here is my code.

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(mtcars, x = "wt", y = "mpg", 
       add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
       cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
       xlab = "Weight (1000 lbs)", ylab = "Miles/(US) gallon")
```

Now, I would like to only show the dots for the cars with 6 cylinders ('cyl' = 6) and none of the others.

This seems a very basic question and is probably very simple to answer, but I just could not find a solution anywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting people know that someone kindly answered this question for me, but deleted it, so that I could not vote it up. Here is the person's answer for whoever may find it useful.

```
ggscatter(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ], x = "wt", y = "mpg", 
       add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
       cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
       xlab = "Weight (1000 lbs)", ylab = "Miles/(US) gallon")
```